# Cost effectiveness - Amazon Application Load Balancer vs Amazon EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

At present, we are using Application LoadBalancer with some Ec2 instances at the back. we are getting high charges for ALB usage charges ( around $ 9K) LCU cost. This is high because we have a high volume of requests.

Does replacing the application load balancer with Amazon EKS will help in cost reduction?
The routing of requests to the respective pods will be through Amazon EKS rather than ALB

Comment: EKS uses AWS Application Load Balancers for ingress. Your question is comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to front an ingress controller like NGINX, Traefik, etc with an AWS load balancer; either the ALB or the NLB. You "could" create a node port service for the ingress controller and forego using a load balancer, but I wouldn't recommend it as it requires you to expose the worker nodes on which the NGINX pods are running to the Internet. Another option would be to run your own load balancer/reverse proxy, but then you'd have to manage it yourself.